# WPF - Toggle Visibility of multiple windows

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface

i will first explain the UI of my WPF App.

I have created a window which contains many buttons which is always visible to the user(lets call it main window), each button will open a new window relevant to the task. what i want done is that whenever a button is clicked, the main window should be hidden(visibility : collapsed) and the new window should be shown. This second window will also contain a button which will hide the second window and show back the main window.
also the second window which will be opening will have different dimensions as per the command associated with it so i will be having different windows for eaach

TLDR i want to be able to switch between multiple windows such that only one window is visible at one time, how do i manage the switching between multiple windows ??

Note : I can show the second window from main window but what about showing main from the second window....can't get it....or if anyone can show me a different approach to implement this : other than multiple windows

Also, this is an extension to the UI, i want to show the buttons in this crystalised sort of look like on this page : http://postimage.org/image/4yibiulsh/
can anyone direct me to a proper implementation, i have been through many sites and also tried to create these through blend but i just am not a UI Person....pls need help on this
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could pass the instance of the mainwindow in the constructor of the second window. But I don't understand why you don't just close the second window if you go back to the mainwindow?

Comment: if i close the window won't i have to load all the elements and data as well when the user clicks on the button again, hiding it and then closing it when the main application closes seems a better idea...right ??

Comment: I'm not sure, you will have all the data in memory, even when it is not needed. Using panels like Jon suggested would be better.

Comment: i am repeating what i wrote below : "And also i had considered using panels (different grids actually) but the window size differs too much and also the placement of windows is different....one is like a sidebar, one for notification, one for settings in center of screen....it wont be easy to manage all via one window"....or will it be in fact more easy, i am asking your opinion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a "Window manager" which will subscribe to the changes of opening/closing.
In this case you don't have to overload Window classes. 
Example (worked for me).

```
public class WindowsManager
{
    static readonly List<Window> Windows=new List<Window>();

    public static T CreateWindow<T>(T window) where T:Window
    {
        Windows.Add(window);
        window.Closed += WindowClosed;
        window.IsVisibleChanged += WindowIsVisibleChanged;
        return window;
    }

    static void WindowIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().Single();
        mainWindow.Visibility = Equals(e.NewValue, true) ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    static void WindowClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var window = (Window) sender;
        window.Closed -= WindowClosed;
        window.IsVisibleChanged -= WindowIsVisibleChanged;
        Windows.Remove(window);
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsManager.CreateWindow(new Child1()).Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowsManager.CreateWindow(new Child2()).Show();
    }
```

So, when the child window will close, WindowsManager will be notified about this and will update visibility for the main window

**UPD1.** 
added line to unscubscribe from VisibleChanged

Comment: wow....that is a really great example.....i am going to try that and let you know what happens....just one question though : is this proper that if i close any of the secondary windows, then i call the close events of all the other windows and then application.shutdown from here ?? or should it be handled in a different manner ??...but thank you for that piece of code...

Comment: @Billy depends on your logic. Generally I would avoid that. But again - it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several approaches for that.

To easy switch back to main Window: inject a reference of your MainWindow to your SecondWindow (or any other Window you want to display) and in the Closing Event of that Window you set the Visibility of the MainWindow back to Visible.

Have you also considered keeping everything in the same Window but having different Panels that you set Visible and Invisible? That could have the same effect but it's less complicated...

Hope that helps...

Comment: thank you for the reference bit, but tell me this if i close the second window(exit the application) how will i manage shutting down the application in that case ?? I want to propagate the exit event and close all windows....And also i had considered using panels (different grids actually) but the window size differs too much and also the placement of windows is different....one is like a sidebar, one for notification, one for settings in center of screen....it wont be easy to manage all via one window, right ??

Comment: also anything about those UI buttons....i liked that interface and wanted to get it.....